# Changing text size according to the change in the button size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a toggle button that changes it's size as following :

```
protected int[] calculateCardWidth(int[] rowsCols) {
        //Getting the screen size.
        Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
        //cardWidHigh 0->width , 1 ->height.
        cardWidHigh[0] = (int) (width / (rowsCols[1] + .25));
        cardWidHigh[1] = (int) (height / (rowsCols[0] + 2));
     return cardWidHigh;
}
```

I want to be able to change the text size according to the change in button size (it's width and height )dynamically, what is the best approach inorder to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You change the values of its LayoutParams, the parent will use the new values to rerender the screen at new positions:

```
LayoutParams p = cardView.getLayoutParams();
p.width = cardWidth[0];
p.height = cardWidth[1];
cardView.setLayoutParams(p);
cardView.getViewParent().invalidate();
```

Comment: It's not necessarily specified for cardView right? Can I use it with a grid layout for example?
and  still I don't get how this would be related to the text size each time the button's size change?